# zen cart fast and easy checkout

Tags: php, checkout, zen-cart

I loaded the latest version of the Fast and Easy Checkout Plugin for ZenCart. (2.1.8) I'm using ZenCart version 1.5.5 MySQL 5.5.45 and PHP 5.4.45 .

It is not working and I'm finding this in my log:

```
[23-Jun-2016 20:18:55 UTC] Request URI: /zen-cart-v155/thiRd-EMP-Brick/configuration.php?gID=32, IP address: 208.102.139.70
#1  trigger_error() called at [/home/dblisasmith/public_html/zen-cart-v155/includes/functions/plugin_support.php:68]
#2  plugin_version_check_for_updates() called at [/home/dblisasmith/public_html/zen-cart-v155/thiRd-EMP-Brick/includes/init_includes/init_css_js_loader_config.php:79]
#3  require(/home/dblisasmith/public_html/zen-cart-v155/thiRd-EMP-Brick/includes/init_includes/init_css_js_loader_config.php) called at [/home/dblisasmith/public_html/zen-cart-v155/includes/autoload_func.php:48]
#4  require(/home/dblisasmith/public_html/zen-cart-v155/includes/autoload_func.php) called at [/home/dblisasmith/public_html/zen-cart-v155/thiRd-EMP-Brick/includes/application_top.php:171]
#5  require_once(/home/dblisasmith/public_html/zen-cart-v155/thiRd-EMP-Brick/includes/application_top.php) called at [/home/dblisasmith/public_html/zen-cart-v155/thiRd-EMP-Brick/configuration.php:12]

[23-Jun-2016 20:18:55 UTC] PHP Notice:  CURL error checking plugin versions: 28:Connection timed out after 9000 milliseconds
Trying file_get_contents() instead. in /home/dblisasmith/public_html/zen-cart-v155/includes/functions/plugin_support.php on line 68
```

I've been working on this for two days to get this far, and I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

there is a folder called extras and within there is a curltester.php script.

i would ensure that curl is working first from that script.  you might have to edit the .htaccess file in that directory to get that script to load.

the error does not seem related to FEC.